# How to get Kotlin AST?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, kotlin

I have a string with Kotlin source in it. How can I compile it at run-time and get abstract syntax tree and types info to analyze?

Comment: I built a project to do this (with AST, but not types): https://github.com/cretz/kastree

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have some investigation of Kotlin compiler. Some proof of concept to getting of AST can be seen on my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/vektory79/kotlin-script-parser-test).

It's a sketch only, but can be helpful:

```
class KotlinScriptParser {
    companion object {
        private val LOG = Logger.getLogger(KotlinScriptParser.javaClass.name)
        private val messageCollector = object : MessageCollector {
            override fun report(severity: CompilerMessageSeverity, message: String, location: CompilerMessageLocation) {
                val path = location.path
                val position = if (path == null) "" else "$path: (${location.line}, ${location.column}) "

                val text = position + message

                if (CompilerMessageSeverity.VERBOSE.contains(severity)) {
                    LOG.finest(text)
                } else if (CompilerMessageSeverity.ERRORS.contains(severity)) {
                    LOG.severe(text)
                } else if (severity == CompilerMessageSeverity.INFO) {
                    LOG.info(text)
                } else {
                    LOG.warning(text)
                }
            }
        }

        private val classPath: ArrayList<File> by lazy {
            val classpath = arrayListOf<File>()
            classpath += PathUtil.getResourcePathForClass(AnnotationTarget.CLASS.javaClass)
            classpath
        }
    }

    fun parse(vararg files: String): TopDownAnalysisContext {
        // The Kotlin compiler configuration
        val configuration = CompilerConfiguration()

        val groupingCollector = GroupingMessageCollector(messageCollector)
        val severityCollector = MessageSeverityCollector(groupingCollector)
        configuration.put(CLIConfigurationKeys.MESSAGE_COLLECTOR_KEY, severityCollector)


        configuration.addJvmClasspathRoots(PathUtil.getJdkClassesRoots())
        // The path to .kt files sources
        files.forEach { configuration.addKotlinSourceRoot(it) }
        // Configuring Kotlin class path
        configuration.addJvmClasspathRoots(classPath)
        configuration.put(JVMConfigurationKeys.MODULE_NAME, JvmAbi.DEFAULT_MODULE_NAME)
        configuration.put<List<AnalyzerScriptParameter>>(JVMConfigurationKeys.SCRIPT_PARAMETERS, CommandLineScriptUtils.scriptParameters())

        val rootDisposable = Disposer.newDisposable()
        try {
            val environment = KotlinCoreEnvironment.createForProduction(rootDisposable, configuration, EnvironmentConfigFiles.JVM_CONFIG_FILES)
            val ktFiles = environment.getSourceFiles()
            val sharedTrace = CliLightClassGenerationSupport.NoScopeRecordCliBindingTrace()
            val moduleContext = TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.createContextWithSealedModule(environment.project,
                    environment.getModuleName())

            val project = moduleContext.project
            val allFiles = JvmAnalyzerFacade.getAllFilesToAnalyze(project, null, ktFiles)
            val providerFactory = FileBasedDeclarationProviderFactory(moduleContext.storageManager, allFiles)
            val lookupTracker = LookupTracker.DO_NOTHING
            val packagePartProvider = JvmPackagePartProvider(environment)
            val container = createContainerForTopDownAnalyzerForJvm(
                    moduleContext,
                    sharedTrace,
                    providerFactory,
                    GlobalSearchScope.allScope(project),
                    lookupTracker,
                    packagePartProvider)

            val additionalProviders = ArrayList<PackageFragmentProvider>()

            additionalProviders.add(container.javaDescriptorResolver.packageFragmentProvider)

            return container.lazyTopDownAnalyzerForTopLevel.analyzeFiles(TopDownAnalysisMode.LocalDeclarations, allFiles, additionalProviders)
        } finally {
            rootDisposable.dispose()
            if (severityCollector.anyReported(CompilerMessageSeverity.ERROR)) {
                throw RuntimeException("Compilation error")
            }
        }
    }
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scriptFile = "/media/data/java/blackfern/kotlin-compile-test/test.kt"

    val parser = KotlinScriptParser()
    // Getting a root element of the AST
    val analyzeContext = parser.parse(scriptFile)
    // Sample AST investigation
    val function = analyzeContext.functions.keys.first()
    val body = function.bodyExpression as KtBlockExpression
}
```

Comment: Please include the essential parts of linked resource in the answer itself, so-called "link only" answers should be avoided.

Answer (score 7):

There's no standard API to do this at the moment. You can play with the Kotlin compiler and REPL [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin) to try to achieve this.

Comment: Any start points? Relevant unit tests, maybe, class names? I understand that there is no API, but I'd appreciate any hints about where to start or which classes to look.

Comment: Well, it's rather complicated, to be honest. You can look into how our `ExpressionTypingVisitor` classes work, also there's a concept of PSI — a concrete syntax tree,and BindingContext — a mapping from PSI to type information an other semantic information. PSI classes are prefixed with `Jet`

Comment: What is the status right now? Is there or will there be an api for that purpose?

Comment: @user3464741 No real changes, we may expose such an API at some point, but currently this is not a high-priority task

Comment: @Andrey is there any place where users can vote for features like this one?

Comment: And what is the status today, one more year after my last question? How can I get a typechecked syntax tree for more than one .kt source file?

Comment: @Michael No changes so far, you can still use the source code of the compiler and the IDE plugin to achieve what you need.